# awk regex how can I match or capture this string

Tags: regex, bash, awk

How do I match or capture these strings:

So far, have tried these two regex patterns that both achieve the same logical matches:

`/file="ZZ([^-]+)-[^"]+\.XML"/` - awk

`/(?<=ZZ)\w++/` - not supported in awk

Text to be processed in awk:

```
file="ZZ12345678-20170101.XML"
file="ZZ87654321-19990101.XML"
file="ZZAA123456-20170101.XML"
file="ZZAA123456-20170101.XML"
file="ZZAA123456A1-20170101.XML"
file="ZZBB654321B2-19990101.XML"
file="ZZCC123456C3-20170101.XML"
```

The problem match is the one letter and one number `A1` , `B2` , `C3` after the series of numbers. The problem is always the single letter and number after the series of numbers.

`file="ZZ12345678-20170101.XML"` correctly matches `12345678`

`file="ZZ87654321-19990101.XML"` correctly matches `87654321`

`file="ZZAA123456-20170101.XML"` correctly matches `AA123456`

`file="ZZBB654321-20170101.XML"` correctly matches `BB654321`

`file="ZZAA123456A1-20170101.XML"` incorrectly matches `AA123456A1` target match `AA123456`

`file="ZZBB654321B2-19990101.XML"` incorrectly matches `BB654321B2` target match `BB654321`

`file="ZZCC123456C3-20170101.XML"` incorrectly matches `CC123456C3` target match `CC123456`

Grateful for help and example approaches

Comment: it would help if you form single sample input with all given strings and add expected output for that... you've shown regex used, but not how they help in getting whatever output you need... and `awk` doesn't support lookarounds... instead of `ZZ([^-]+)-` using `ZZ([A-Z]*[0-9]+)[A-Z0-9]*-` might help..

Comment: Yes, I see, will form the single input that will be easier to test. Thank you for the information about lookarounds

Comment: `file="ZZBB654321C3-20170101.XML" incorrectly matches BB123456C3 target match CC123456` - you SURE about the expected output for that one?

Comment: apologies, correcting now

Comment: Depending on how complex the cases get , it could be as simple as `grep -oP 'ZZ\K[A-Z]*\d+'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/.*ZZ\([[:upper:]]*[0-9]*\).*/\1/' file
12345678
87654321
AA123456
BB654321
AA123456
BB654321
BB654321
```

or with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/ZZ([[:upper:]]*[0-9]*)/,a){print a[1]}' file
12345678
87654321
AA123456
BB654321
AA123456
BB654321
BB654321
```

or also GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/.*ZZ([[:upper:]]*[0-9]*).*/,"\\1",1)}' file
12345678
87654321
AA123456
BB654321
AA123456
BB654321
BB654321
```

Comment: GNU awk for the 3rd arg worked nicely, thank you again.

Comment: Nice post. Could you please explain me what "[:upper:]" does? Thanks

Comment: @Patrick85 it's the POSIX character class representing the set of all upper case letters in your locale. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#table_002dchar_002dclasses

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. That was new to me. Now i learned something more. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
awk '{match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/);print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2);}' Input_file
```

Using awk's match function which is looking for regex from alphabets to till digits and then printing it's substring which starts from RSTART+2 and till the length of RLENGTH-2.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^file=\"ZZ([A-Z]*[0-9]+)[^-]*-[^"]+\.XML\"$/\1/' file

12345678
87654321
AA123456
BB654321
AA123456
BB654321
BB654321
```

Or you can use `gnu-awk`:

```
awk '{print gensub(/^file=\"ZZ([A-Z]*[0-9]+)[^-]*-[^"]+\.XML\"$/, "\\1", "1")}' file
```

Or using `gnu grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=file=\"ZZ)([A-Z]*[0-9]+)(?=[^-]*-[^"]+\.XML\"$)' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{print substr($0,9,8)}' file 

12345678
87654321
AA123456
AA123456
AA123456
BB654321
BB654321
```

Comment: Not sure the field separator is needed.